# ¿Como Calcular el MSE en múltiples filas de un data frame?

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr

Tengo un data frame (datos) que tiene ocho columnas y 2006 observaciones,

[image: datos]

de estas columnas quiero calcular MSE para Pcp_Estacion y Pcp_Chirps, usando la función de MSE de la librería de MLmetrics, Pero quiero calcularlos por estación y por mes para obtener un data frame calculado para cada mes y cada estación meteorológica, en el ejemplo calculo el MSE para las cinco estaciones meteorológicas que tengo para el mes de julio, ¿Hay una manera más rápida de hacer todo esto a la vez, para todos los meses y las estaciones meteorológicas?

```
# Cargar librerías
library(tidyverse);
library(dplyr);
library(Metrics);
library(MLmetrics);

# Cargar los datos
datos <- read.csv("Base_mse.csv")


# Visualizar las primeras 10 observaciones
head(datos, 10)
    X Mes Year Estacion variable  n Pcp_Chirps Pcp_Estacion
1   1   1 1982    11024      Pcp 30      0.262        0.000
2   2   1 1982    11033      Pcp 31      0.190        0.045
3   3   1 1982    11141      Pcp 31      0.265        0.000
4   4   2 1982    11024      Pcp 28      0.317        0.286
5   5   2 1982    11033      Pcp 28      0.242        0.629
6   6   2 1982    11141      Pcp 28      0.351        0.500
7   7   3 1982    11024      Pcp 31      0.000        2.903
8   8   3 1982    11033      Pcp 31      0.148        0.000
9   9   3 1982    11141      Pcp 31      0.000        0.000
10 10   4 1982    11024      Pcp 30      0.543        0.800

# filtratr por mes y por estacion
mse_11024_7 <- filter(datos, Mes == 7, Estacion %in% c("11024"))
mse_11033_7 <- filter(datos, Mes == 7, Estacion %in% c("11033"))
mse_11060_7 <- filter(datos, Mes == 7, Estacion %in% c("11060"))
mse_11096_7 <- filter(datos, Mes == 7, Estacion %in% c("11096"))
mse_11141_7 <- filter(datos, Mes == 7, Estacion %in% c("11141"))


# Calcular el mse() de julio para cada estación meteorológica
MSE(mse_11024_7$Pcp_Estacion, mse_11024_7$Pcp_Chirps)
MSE(mse_11033_7$Pcp_Estacion, mse_11033_7$Pcp_Chirps)
MSE(mse_11060_7$Pcp_Estacion, mse_11060_7$Pcp_Chirps)
MSE(mse_11096_7$Pcp_Estacion, mse_11096_7$Pcp_Chirps)
MSE(mse_11141_7$Pcp_Estacion, mse_11141_7$Pcp_Chirps)

> MSE(mse_11024_7$Pcp_Estacion, mse_11024_7$Pcp_Chirps)
[1] 2.435242
> MSE(mse_11033_7$Pcp_Estacion, mse_11033_7$Pcp_Chirps)
[1] 1.086456
> MSE(mse_11060_7$Pcp_Estacion, mse_11060_7$Pcp_Chirps)
[1] 2.626344
> MSE(mse_11096_7$Pcp_Estacion, mse_11096_7$Pcp_Chirps)
[1] 2.887427
> MSE(mse_11141_7$Pcp_Estacion, mse_11141_7$Pcp_Chirps)
[1] 9.519657
```

¿Hay una manera más rápida de hacer todo esto a la vez, para todos los meses y para cada estación meteorológica?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entiendo que lo que estarías buscando es el `mse` de cada grupo de observaciones formado por el `Mes` y la `Estacion` (¿el año no?), en cuyo caso, simplemente deberías (a) agrupar (b) sumarizar:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Mes, Estacion) %>% 
  summarize(mse = MSE(Pcp_Estacion, Pcp_Chirps))
```

Comment: Patricio, eso es exactamente lo que estaba buscando, automatizar el calculo del MSE para cada mes, muchas gracias.